# how I use tor on windows phone?

Tags: security

since the wifi that I am using does not allow me even to connect to my vpn, the only way that I have to visit facebook etc. is surfing with Tor browser, as I do on my laptop.
Is there a way to use the Tor network on my phone with windows phone 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no supported version of Tor or the Tor Browser that would allow you to connect to the Tor Network in Windows Phone. However, you can buy a Raspberry Pi and set it up as a Tor router, then to connect to that "Torified" Wifi.

Comment: This can only be done with a raspberry pi?